# Homeomorphism $(Y, \mathrm{T}(d_{e})|Y)$ with $(X, \mathrm{T}(d_{e})|X)$

Tags: general-topology

$\newcommand{\Tau}{\mathrm{T}}$

> Let: $$X_n=\left\{ (\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n+m}): m=1,2,... \right\},$$ $$X=\left\{(0,0)\right\} \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n  \text{       and    } Y \subset X.$$
>   For the subspace $(X, \Tau(d_{e})|X)$and $(Y, \Tau(d_{e})|Y)$ of euclidean space $(\mathbb R^2, \Tau(d_{e}))$ prove that:
>   
> **1)** if exist $n_0$ such that for $n\ge n_0$ intersection $Y \cap X_n$ is a finite set  then $(Y, \Tau(d_{e})|Y)$ is not homeomorphic with $(X, \Tau(d_{e})|X)$;
>   
>  **2)** if $\left\{(0,0)\right\} \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_{2n} \subset Y$ then spaces $(Y, \Tau(d_{e})|Y)$ and $(X, \Tau(d_{e})|X)$ are homeomorphic.

1) I think that the best idea to do this task is assume that if exist $n_0$ such that for $n\ge n_0$ intersection $Y \cap X_n$ is a finite set  then $(Y, \Tau(d_{e})|Y)$ **IS** homeomorphic with $(X, \Tau(d_{e})|X)$ and show that it is contradiction.

So if homeomorphic exist then we have that exist $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is injective, surjective, continuous and also $f^{-1}$ is continuous. 

 However I don't know how to show that this is contradiction.

Comment: Two is false when Y =:R.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Y can't be equal $\mathbb R$ because $Y \subset X$

Comment: In that case Y = R - {100} is a counter example.